# Is there a simple way to keep git history when moving 2 rust applications into a workspace?

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo

While it is not existential, I think it is interesting to see, how it would work.
The current situation is, that I have two (bare) remote git repos `a1.git, a2.git`,
one for a rust application crate, each. Now, I want to evolve both apps in a rust workspace where they can share dependencies (avoiding duplicate code). This workspace will be a remote `apps.git` repository eventually.

Before:

```
./a1
./a2
```

After:

```
./w/a1
./w/a2
./w/d1..dn
```

I could simply do it locally, forget about the 2 old repositories and create a new one.
But, if it is not all too messy, is there a way to carry the history over into the new `apps.git`?

Comment: @PitaJ I glanced over that one before, but was not sure if this is my use case. There might be provisions with cargo. And I will have to move stuff from the old `Cargo.toml`s into the new top level one. So there might be rust/cargo specific shortcuts.

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with `cargo`. It's a pure `git` problem.

Comment: Agreed, there's very minimal work to do cargo-wise to move two packages into a workspace. You don't even have to modify any `Cargo.toml`s since a new one can be put at the workspace root that will supersede the nested ones (just make sure to list them as `members`). The only provision would be if you're concerned about persisting the dependency versions from your `Cargo.lock` files, but in a practical sense you will likely be fine with regenerating it.

Comment: But what I said above has nothing to do with preserving git history. It is a completely different system.